# XMLRPC Response Using ws-xmlrpc

Tags: java, service, xml-rpc

Anyone have experience parsing complex response types using `ws-xmlrpc`?

The `Service` returns a `HashMap` with one of the values an `Array`, when I request the key of the `Array` from the `HashMap`,  Java just returns `java.lang.Object`.

How do I access the contents of the `Array`?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the default java Object to HashMap and then access it.